# Continue the Ford-Fulkelson

Tags: ford-fulkerson

I am trying to learn the Ford-Fulkerson method. I've made up an example for practicing and at some point I can't continue incrementing the flow but I know the flow could be higher.

[image]

First of all, I have incremented the path `s -> 1 -> 2 -> t`. And now I can't find any path for incrementing the flow. I know that if I took path `a -> 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> t` first, then I could increment path `s -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> t` but if I had to implement it I wouldn't know how to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't know that it was possible to use edges in the opposite direction to the arrow.

[image]

So we can traverse the path `s -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> t`.

[image]

Then we get the expected result.